# Ads closed by google buttons using AdMob

Tags: android, admob

I'm new to AdMob. I did a test without clicking on the Ad.

It works fine but my problem is that the Ad banner appears with 2 buttons on a side as below

[image]

When I click on one of these buttons, it says: Ad closed by Google

[image]

I have used a 60 sec refresh time between Ads, so the next Ad appears after 60 sec.

What is the issue? Is this behavior normal?

I think I use a simple code:

```
    AdView mAdView;
    mAdView = (AdView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and the layout:

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: How do you get this close button? I'm using Native ads with a request for a custom mute, but i want to use the default one provided by google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is normal. It's something Google and a lot of other ad networks do in order to give users more control over the ad experience.

There are two buttons you're seeing in your ad. One is a close button, which allows users to close an ad they don't want to see. This lets Google know that it might be an offensive or spammy ad that slipped through the cracks and should be filtered out of the system.

The other is the [AdChoices](http://youradchoices.com/) icon from the [Digital Advertising Alliance](http://digitaladvertisingalliance.org/). If you tap on it, you'll be taken to a page explaining which network showed you the ad, what their privacy policy is, and a bunch of other details. It's a way of making sure that your users are informed about who's showing them ads and how.

Comment: I just enjoyed today the 12 videos you did :) Thanks for the explanation. I will send another question on Ad Banner Vs screen size. I'm struggling on it. if you could keep an eye on it....

Answer (score 0):

I've checked several applications and it seems to be the normal behavior. It looks to be weird to let the user remove the Ads.

But this is the way it seems to work.